# transparent button background w/ v7.app.AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat, android-styles

Anyone ever see this weird styling quirk[image]?
Android support libraries 23.4.0 (can't move to latest yet because of a bunch of code changes).

@style/AlertDialogTheme
...

   
        @color/themeColor

Using v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder, the setView needs to be called w/ R.style.AlertDialogTheme for the theme to show up on Android 4.x (no need for Android 5.x and above).  AppCompatDialogFragment is also being used instead of DialogFragment.

Comment: are running on emulator?

Comment: Yes...the Nexus9 genymotion emulator